# Storage Space Direct

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016, windows-cluster

Can you add Storage Space Direct to existing V nets on azure? (without using template) if so please explain.
I have 2 Windows server 2016 already installed on azure, I just wanted to add a storage space direct cluster for those servers without using template.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Storage spaces direct is not really Azure aware. You have two VMs running, you just configure them to run Storage Spaces Direct as you would an on premesis machine - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/deploy-storage-spaces-direct

Comment: Sam, according to MSFT stats they declared 50% of the S2D deployments are in Azure.

Comment: Right, but that’s not really got much to do with this answer. You can install S2D in Azure,  but the process for installing it is not Azure specific.

Comment: Sam, I'm sorry but this is BS you post here. 1) "not really Azure aware" and "installation is not Azure specific" are two quite different things, 2) You can use templates with Azure Resource Manager to deploy S2D, so  S2D is (are?) Azure-aware :) https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2017/03/21/step-by-step-deploy-windows-server-2016-storage-spaces-direct-s2d-cluster-in-microsoft-azure/

Comment: Ok firstly there is no need for the attitude. Secondly my comment on S2D not being Azure aware is correct. S2D is not aware that it is installed in Azure, it doesn’t detect that it is running in an Azure vNet it doesn’t  do anything special to work with Azure. Yes you can install it in Azure but the process to do so is no different to doing it on premesis.  The templates you refer to are doing two things, firstly deploying the Azure infrastructure which is all done using ARM templates and then installing S2D using PowerShell DSC, this DSC could also be run on prem, it is not Azure specific.

Comment: If you can use originally Azure-provided scripts to auto-install S2D on premises, it doesn't make then "not Azure specific" (c) you. IMHO. I think we can agree to disagree here as I don't see any strong points taken.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can setup S2D in Azure adding to existing VLANs. It can be done as you would setup S2D on-site https://www.tech-coffee.net/2-node-hyperconverged-cluster-with-windows-server-2016/

Since you need shared storage in Azure, I do not think S2D is an option here. The shared storage can be done using Shared VHDXs over redundant underlying Azure object storage. (Azure handle storage redundancy).

S2D does not allow you to setup stretched (multi-site) clusters, so I do not see any sense to use it here. 
Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-replica/stretch-cluster-replication-using-shared-storage 
With this being said, try StarWind Virtual SAN that does the same job of shared storage but features stretched cluster storage in Azure. https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/starwind.starwindvirtualsan